# How to create left axis with variable tick interval in tick values and has same distance between tick value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, math, svg

I am creating left axis and the current output is like this.

[image: this].

The problem is there is a gap between tick values but i want uniform gap between two tick values as here.

[image: here]

Here is the [Code example](https://jsbin.com/tuwesip/3/edit?html,js,output).

```
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axisLeft")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y1).tickValues(y1TickValues).tickSizeOuter(0).tickFormat(d3.format("d")))
        .selectAll('text')
        .style('text-anchor', 'end');
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is impossible. The reason is simple: a linear scale is a **continuous** scale. That is, it deals with a continuous (non-discrete) quantitative variable.

The only way for you to **guarantee** that the distance between the ticks is rigorously the **same** is using an ordinal scale, but those scales deal with qualitative (categorical) variables. Not what you want.

However, there is a hack: using a log scale. In this case, since your domain crosses zero, well use a symlog scale (avoiding the log of zero, which in math is not a real number), available on D3 v5 (not v4, the version you're using). By using a symlog scale with `constant(100)`...

```
var y1 = d3.scaleSymlog()
    .constant(100)
    .domain([0,2000]).range([height,0]);
```

... we get something similar (but not exactly like) to what you asked:

[image]

Here is the updated code:

```js
(function(window){

    var graphData = [1699, 725, 1149, 868, 304, 1844, 745, 1846, 1423, 1739, 823, 1404, 226, 1603, 389, 517, 1452, 1842, 930, 547, 1072, 828, 733, 632];
    var timeArr = [];
    for (var i=0;i<24;i++) {
        timeArr.push(i);
    }

    function trans(key){
        return key;
    }

    drawEditGraph();

    function drawEditGraph() {
        var dataGraph = { timeArr:timeArr, graphData:graphData};

        function make_x_gridlines() {
            return d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(height).tickValues(xTicks)
                .ticks(10)
        }

        var margin = {top: 35, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
            width = $(window).width() - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = $(window).height() - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        var svgHeight = height + 40;
        var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);

        var tickValues= [0,4,8,12,16,20,24];
        var y1TickValues = [20,50,75,100,150,200,300,400,500,750,1000,1500,2000]
        x.domain([0,23]);

        var y1 = d3.scaleSymlog()
        .constant(100)
        .domain([0,2000]).range([height,0]);


        var xTicks = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
        var valueline2 = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .y(function(d) { return y1(d.open); });

        var svg = d3.select("#graphDiv").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", svgHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var data = [];
        for (var i=0;i<dataGraph.timeArr.length;i++){
            var obj = {};
            obj.date = dataGraph.timeArr[i];
            obj.open = dataGraph.graphData[i];

            data.push(obj)
        }

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "grid")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+(height)+")")
            .call(make_x_gridlines()
                .tickSize(-width)
                .tickSizeOuter(0)
                .tickFormat("")
            )

        svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline2);



        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axisBottom")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickValues(xTicks).tickFormat(function(d,i){
                if (d<10)
                    return "0"+d;
                return d;
            }));

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axisLeft")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y1).tickValues(y1TickValues).tickSizeOuter(0).tickFormat(d3.format("d")))
            .selectAll('text')
            .style('text-anchor', 'end');



        //Add title
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "center")
            .attr("x", (width/2) - 25)
            .attr("y", height + 35 )
            .attr("fill", "#8E8E8E")
            .attr("font-size", "12")
            .text(trans("Time"));

        // Y0 axis label:
        svg.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
            .attr("y", -23)
            .attr("x",  5)
            .attr("font-size", "12")
            .attr("fill", "#725100")
            .text(trans("Colour"));

        svg.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
            .attr("y", -8)
            .attr("x", 5)
            .attr("font-size", "12")
            .attr("fill", "#725100")
            .text("("+trans("K") + ")");

    }

}(window));
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #FFC841 ;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.axisSteelBlue text{
  fill: #FFC841;
}

.axisRed text{
  fill: #5BCBD4;
}



.grid line {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Graph Demo">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Graph Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.2/d3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="graphDiv">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have got desired output by using a linear scale and by mapping my data to linear scale back and vice versa. [Example](https://jsbin.com/tuwesip/8/edit?js,output)